# Advanced usage of LUTs in Lightroom (masking; using more than one LUT)

Tags: lightroom, photoshop

I really like working with LUTs (color Lookup Tables). But I think Lightroom is missing some functionalities in this regard, or I cannot find them.  Is it possible to:

1. Use more than one LUT in processing of a single photo?
2. Use LUTs as an adjustment brush and/or mask some areas of the photo from using LUTs?

Both of these things are easy to achieve in Photoshop (Color Lookup adjustment layer(s) with masks) ... but Photoshop workflow is so slow in comparison to fast developing of photos in Lightroom.

Comment: "Both of these things are easy to achieve in Photoshop (Color Lookup adjustment layer(s) with masks) .. but Photoshop workflow is so slow in comparison to fast developing of photos in Lightroom." Do you think maybe the ability to do these type of operations are what causes Photoshop to be slower?

Comment: I didn't mean processing speed itself (CPU consumption etc.), but the speed of switching between the photos, stuff like that. 'LUT adjustment brush' wouldn't slow it down.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, sort of. You can apply multiple profiles/LUT's to the same image, but not a single image. You would need to export the image in a non-raw format (tiff/psd/jpeg) and import that image into LR (sync the folder). You can then apply another profile/LUT to the image.
2. Not presently.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about what you proposed in '1.' point also, but this kinda beats the purpose of using LR as a fast tool in comparison to Photoshop workflow :)